# datastax enterprise spatial search

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax

Problem Statement: I am currently trying to configure spatial search in Datastax Enterprise 4.0. I have lat and long as two separate columns in cassandra column family. In what way/ways can I combine lat and long into one comma separated solr spatial search field so that I can take advantage of geofilt, geodist functions. Do I need another column in cassandra which would store lat,long ?

Comment: need your inputs. please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Solr LatLonType which maps to a Cassandra UTF8Type.

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.0/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchSolrType.html

Comment: Thanks. Added another column to the CF and that worked. Is there any way to do away with adding another column with lat,long value ? Also, does DSE 4.0 support Solr spatialrecursiveprefixtreefieldtype ?

Comment: > Is there any way to do away with adding another column with lat,long value?  Not really.  spatialrecursiveprefixtreefieldtype should map to a UTF8Type and work.